# How to save counter of entries in str and show it in Text field?

Tags: python, tkinter, scope, counter

Using such example i want to count number of entries. And represent string with number of entries in Text field. Like, for example:

```
1: number of entries(1)
21: number of entries(2)
...
```

Where should i put my counter variable?

```
import random
from tkinter import *

class MyApp(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()        

    def create_widgets(self):

        Label(self, text = 'Your number:').grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.num_ent = Entry(self)
        self.num_ent.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Button(self, text = 'Check', command = self.update).grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)
        self.user_text = Text(self, width = 50, height = 40, wrap = WORD)
        self.user_text.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

    def update(self):

        guess = self.num_ent.get()
        guess += '\n'
        self.user_text.insert(0.0, guess)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('410x200')
root.title('Entries counter')
app = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, simply keep count of the number of button presses, you can define a count variable in `__init__` like

```
self.count = 0
```

And increase and print it in `update` like

```
def update(self):
    self.count += 1
    guess = self.num_ent.get()
    guess += '\n'
    self.user_text.insert(0.0, 'Guess #{}: {}'.format(self.count, guess))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using Python 3.

The easiest way to store your counter is to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). The key would be the text you're counting (1 and 21 according to your example), the value stores the count itself (e.g. 1 and 2).

The structured data for your example would look like this:

```python
{
  '1':  1,
  '21': 2
}
```

And the final code:

```python
from tkinter import *

class MyApp(Frame):
  def __init__(self, master):
    super(MyApp, self).__init__(master)

    #this is your counter variable
    self.entries = {}

    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()        

  def create_widgets(self):
    Label(self, text = 'Your number:').grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
    self.num_ent = Entry(self)
    self.num_ent.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
    Button(self, text = 'Check', command = self.update).grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)
    self.user_text = Text(self, width = 50, height = 40, wrap = WORD)
    self.user_text.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

  def update(self):
    #get the new entry from the text field and strip whitespaces
    new_entry = self.num_ent.get().strip()

    #check if the entry is already in the counter variable
    if new_entry in self.entries:
      #if it is: increment the counter
      self.entries[new_entry] += 1
    else:
      #if it's not: add it and set its counter to 1
      self.entries[new_entry] = 1

    #delete the whole text area
    self.user_text.delete('0.0', END)

    #get every entry from the counter variable, sorted alphabetically
    for key in sorted(self.entries):
      #insert the entry at the end of the text area
      self.user_text.insert(END, '{}: number of entries({})\n'.format(key, self.entries[key]))

root = Tk()
root.geometry('410x200')
root.title('Entries counter')
app = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```